# Generated Angular attributes for CSS scoping not getting applied to inner elements of components

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

Angular generates attributes and appears to apply them only to elements you have declared in your template. Any additional HTML elements which come with a component (in my case, angular-material's `mat-form-field`) do not get this attribute applied.

Is this by design? The effect of it is that there is no way to target those inner elements, as any classes which you define in your component's css file get concatenated with the attribute Angular generates.

In my case,

```
.mat-form-field * {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Generates to:

```
mat-form-field[_ngcontent-c19] *[_ngcontent-c19] {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

My goal is to style some of the many HTML elements which a `<mat-form-field>` is comprised of.

Is there any way to achieve this from within my component's files (without resorting to a site-wide stylesheet)?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `::ng-deep` selector, so `mat-form-field ::ng-deep *` should do what you want

Comment: I think `::ng-deep` is deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: @pnadalini It is, but the official advise from that page is `Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ::ng-deep instead of /deep/ which is seems like deprecated.

```
mat-form-field ::ng-deep *
```

Per documentation:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

You can find it [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: What will be the preferred method once those three are deprecated? Is there any other method?

Comment: According to that quote you've added, we should prefer the use of `::ng-deep` over `/deep/`

Comment: First I wrote what was on the top of my head, but then I realized that ::ng-deep is preferred for now. That is why I included the documentation in my answer.

Comment: You may want to update your answer to follow that recommendation

Comment: Sorry if my answer was misleading for the first time. I updated it.